# Почему не работают EditText

Tags: android

В общем, использую вот эту библиотеку: https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism

Написал вот такой код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Sign_In" >

    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
        android:id="@+id/neumorphCardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:neumorph_lightSource="rightBottom"
        app:neumorph_shapeType="flat">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Почта"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"/>
    </soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>

    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:neumorph_lightSource="rightBottom"
        app:neumorph_shapeType="flat"
        app:neumorph_strokeColor="@color/black"
        app:neumorph_strokeWidth="0.1dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Пароль"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"/>

    </soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>


    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
        android:id="@+id/button_enter"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Войти"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_view"
        app:neumorph_lightSource="rightBottom"
        app:neumorph_shapeType="flat"
        app:neumorph_strokeColor="@color/black"
        app:neumorph_strokeWidth="0.1dp" />

<!--    <FrameLayout-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_sign_in"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">-->

<!--    </FrameLayout>-->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

После теста стало понятно что поле для ввода пароля просто не нажимается(нету клавиатуры, нету курсора и хоть какой-то реакции) хотя поле для почты прекрасно и полностью работает.

Comment: Возможно, у вас вьюхи дру друга перекрывают. Попробуйте их иначе расположить. Ну или попробуйте удалить работающее поле ввода и оставить неработающее - возможно оно заработает. Это подтвердит/опровергнет выдвинутое предположение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, здравствуйте, немного подвинул нижний view, проблема ушла, скорее всего его перекрывает какое-то другое view, не подскажите как это исправить? Если нужно прикреплю файлы которые потребуются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, у вас вьюхи дру друга перекрывают. Попробуйте их иначе расположить. Ну или попробуйте удалить работающее поле ввода и оставить неработающее - возможно оно заработает. Это подтвердит/опровергнет выдвинутое предположение.